# For what value(s) of $p$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{2p}+1}{\sqrt{n+2}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It's a multiple choice question.

My working:

Given series is approximately $$\frac{n^{2p}}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{n^{\frac12-2p}}$$
For the series to converge, $$\frac12-2p>1\implies p<\frac14$$

But that isn't in the options. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{2p}+1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}$$

Comment: So are you saying that there is no value for which the series converges?

Comment: It seems so, don’t you agree?

Comment: Yep. I was just confirming. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Comment: Would that inequality be true for p < 0 as well?

Comment: @pinklemonade yes of course since $\forall p\in \mathbb{R}\quad n^{2p}>0$

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of what you're doing wrong: Two  things. Second, $1/2-2p>1$ does not imply $p>1/4$ as you claim, in fact $1/2-2p>1$ is equivalent to $2p<-1/2$, or $p<-1/4$.

But it does *not*  follow  that the series converges for $p<-1/4$. Because your first estimate, "Given series is approximately..." is only correct for $p>0$; in fact if $p<0$ then the numerator $n^{2p}+1$ is approximately $1$.

You have to be careful with those inequality things...